# MacOS Microphone "Input Level" is not deterministic

Tags: macos, audio, microphone

If I play the same constant beep audio to the microphone, one time I might get:
[image]

And after closing the computer, and opening it later, I might get:

[image]

For the same audio.

1. Why is this happening? Seems like some sort of gain control.
2. Is there a way for me to control this "gain"?

Comment: Potentially related: [Apple.Stack Exchange - Mac OSX microphone input volume level auto-adjusts - can it be disabled?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/97810/mac-osx-microphone-input-volume-level-auto-adjusts-can-it-be-disabled)

Comment: Thanks @esqew, unfortunately, that issue is about "Input Volume" and not "Input Level"